# align to right an element in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've created this elements form:

```
<div class = "ui-grid-a">
                <div class= "ui-block-a">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class = "ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="birth-place">Birth Place</label>
                        <input type="text" name="birth-place" id="birth_place" value="" placeholder="Birth Place" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "ui-block-b">
                    <div data-role = "fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="province">Province</label>
                        <input type="text" name="province" id="province" value="" placeholder="PR" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and I want to align the element `province` to the right. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:
`<span style="float:right"><label for="province">Province</label></span>`
(of course you can put this also in a external css file)

Comment: mmh that's weird normally it should just do what you want:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following...
Apply this custom CSS to your code...

```
label[for="province"] { text-align:right; }
```

If it doesn't run they supply the label with a class name and do the following..

```
label.className { text-align:right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a style of text-align:right;to the input field directly, as in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/den232/Fw2yA/

Good luck!

```
.floatright {
    text-align:right;
 }
    <div data-role="page" class="type-home">
<div data-role="content">

<div class = "ui-grid-a">
<div class= "ui-block-a">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class = "ui-hide-label">
<label for="birth-place">Birth Place</label>
<input type="text" name="birth-place" id="birth_place" value="" placeholder="Birth Place" class='floatright' />
</div>
</div>
<div class = "ui-block-b">
<div data-role = "fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
<label for="province">Province</label>
<input type="text" name="province" id="province" value="" placeholder="PR" />
</div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```