# jquery mobile How to move a select menu to the right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to move select menu to the right edge.
But I don't know how to do...

Here is part of my code.

```
<select name="select-align" id="id-select-align" data-native-menu="false" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="carat-d" data-inline="true">
<option value="1">인기순</option>
<option value="2">판매순</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [align to right an element in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184352/align-to-right-an-element-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Also, you can check for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722139/jquery-mobile-header-button-float-left-and-right)

Answer (score 0):

Please give us some details:

- do you want to align the select menu on the right side of it's container?
- do you want to align the text of the options to the right side of the select menu?

(IMHO: I think this is more a CSS related question rather than a jQuery one)

Comment: First one.
I want to align the select menu on the right side of it's container.